# passing data from controller to view using jquery ajax for line-chart.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, chart.js

I tried to make line-chart.js the data from the database, I used codeigniter with mvc rules, but I was confused when trying to pass data using jquery ajax from the controller to view.

my controller:

```
function debit_sungai_for_grafik(){
    $dsfg = $this->m_data->get_debit_sungai2();
    foreach($dsfg as $d){
        $data[] = (float) $d->kiriQ;
     }
     echo json_encode($data);
     exit();
}
```

view:

```
...
var config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    data: $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "<?php echo site_url("main/debit_sungai_for_grafik") ?>"
                            }),
                    fill: false,
                    borderDash: [5, 5],
                }]
            },
...
```

no data appears. I suspect I'm wrong in the data passing rules. Thank you for the help.

Comment: "<?php echo site_url("main/debit_sungai_for_grafik") ?>" I believe you need single quotes inside the link not double. Also, I personally would store the link in a javascript variable instead of adding php.

Comment: @Icewine thank you for the advice but I have tried it has not been successful too